# "Rails" performance issue: increased processing time on every run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote a method that gets all records from model and performs actions on each of them. When I initially run the method I get somewhat expected result of 0.2s per record. Every repeat of the function increases processing time by a factor of x, but it's not proportional, i.e.: .2 -> .3 -> .6 -> .5 -> .6 -> 1.0 .

Performing a benchmark on parts of the method is telling me that decrease of performance is spread through the whole method - there is no clear indication that only a part of the method would slow down.

SQL response time remains almost the same on every run and they do not seem to be the cause of the issue.

Count of records is correct (it's not processing the same records twice).

I tried clearing all variables upon each call of the method (local_variables.each { |e| eval("#{e} = nil") }), but also this brought no effect.

I understand it's a tricky thing to diagnose based solely on this information, but any direction greatly appreciated.

Adding the method: https://github.com/chungalunga/cncm/blob/master/app/controllers/idents_controller.rb (line 138). Sorry for the code, learning project :) Never mind the function being called 5 times by show method - I just used this to simulate 5 ajax calls on the function.

Thanks!
Dane

Comment: Please show us the code for your method

Comment: That method is far too big to think about. Refactor it appropriately and you'll probably find the culprit anyway.